# Is it possible to dynamically set the timeout in jcarousellite?

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I'd like to set two timers in the jcarouselLITE (take note - not jcarousel). Ideally the first three slides should have timeout:1000, and the forth should have timeout:8000. The following code grabs the index of the current slider and changes the var `variablex` accordingly with the `afterEnd` function:

```
var variablex;
$('.slideshow').jCarouselLite({
    auto: true,         
    afterEnd: function(a){
        var index = $(a[0]).index(); 
        if (index == 3) {
            variablex = 8000;
        }
        else {variablex = 1000;}        
    },
    timeout: variablex;
});
```

I realise that the jCarouselLite function won't keep checking the value for `timeout` - is there some way to assign values to a variable outside the loop with js?

The jcarousellite script can be found here: [github](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite/blob/master/jcarousellite.js)

Comment: As there is no destroy/refresh function i think you need to redo the jCarouselLite function, but you already use the  variablex so it shouldt be a problem. Basicly you should be able to just call it inside afterEnd when it matches the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a raw idea, so it might not work as desired.

```
var slideshowTimeout = 1000;
var $slideShow = $('.slideshow');
var slideshowCount = $slideShow.find('li').length +3;
var isSlowedDown = false;

$slideShow.jCarouselLite({
    auto: true,
    timeout: slideshowTimeout,         
    afterEnd: function(a){
        var index = $(a[0]).index();
        if (index === slideshowCount && isSlowedDown === false) {
            slideshowTimeout = 4000;
            isSlowedDown = true;
            $slideShow.trigger("endCarousel")
            $slideShow.jCarouselLite({
                auto: true,
                timeout: slideshowTimeout,
                start: slideshowCount
            });
        }      
    },
});
```

---

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e2e4V/1/

Comment: you can find it here [link](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite/blob/master/jcarousellite.js)

Comment: Updated the code, can you test it? Else i'll create an JsFiddle :)

Comment: We decided that this wasn't worth the effort so I just built a custom slider - but let's try to fix this anyway for future use? :) Could you create a jsfiddle? The site is live now so I can't really edit it..

Comment: Sure. Created an live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/e2e4V/1/ .. Start at 1 sec pr. item, then goes to 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no timeout option in jCarousel, it's auto the equivalent. Then you can access created jcarousel element after they are initialize

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').data('jcarousel')
```

That will return the instance object for your current carousel, you should be able to change options on the fly by accessing the options object via `jQuery('#mycarousel').data('jcarousel').options`, so you can change the auto option by doing something like

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').data('jcarousel').options.auto = 5;
```

Comment: there is a timeout option - i'm using jcarousellite, not jcarousel - different plugin

Comment: I don't see the timeout option on their documentation either http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/?#doc

Comment: using the update by karl swedberg [here](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite)

Comment: Ah fair enough, there seems to be load of them around, should work the same tho unless the lite version doesn't expose the jcarousel object.